# how to read hex in java to integer

Tags: java

This maybe is a simple question but I couldn't find an answer .

I'm trying to read the hex `7B`, and convert it to it's decimal integer (123), or at least receive the string `7B`.

my code :

```
        byte[] content = new byte[numCharsToRead];

        while ((numBytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(content, 0,
            numCharsToRead)) != -1) {

            String temp=new String(content);
            Log.d("RS232",""+temp);
```

output in logcat :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following for converting to `int`:

```
 String hexDigits = "7b"
 int intValue = Integer.parseInt(hexDigits, 16);
```

Also, the reading part can be simplified to:

```
 String temp; 
 while( (numBytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(content, 0,
        numCharsToRead)) != -1){ 
    temp = new String(contents, 0, numBytesRead);               
 }
```